# A question with the sequence $e_{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Prove that

$a$) the following sequence is increasing
$$e_{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n},\quad n\ge1;$$

$b$) the inequality below holds

$$e_{n} \leq3,\quad n\ge1.$$

Comment: a) also has a [combinatorial proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/90701/5363), see also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/64860/5363) for further arguments.

Comment: @ t.b.: thank you for the link!

Comment: @downvoter: what motivates you to downvote such a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part use the binomial theorem and show that each component is non-decreasing and some are increasing.

For the second part you can use the same binomial expansion term by term to show that $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n<1+1+\frac12+\dots\frac 1{r!}+\dots<1+1+\frac 12+\dots\frac 1 {2^r}+\dots$$ and sum the geometric progression.

Comment: this could be a way! Thanks (+1)

Answer (score 3):

In order to prove that the given sequence is strictly increasing, we are to demonstrate $e_{n+1} > e_n$:

\[ 
\bigg(1+ \dfrac{1}{n+1}\bigg)^{n+1} > \bigg(1 + \dfrac{1}{n} \bigg)^n.
\]

Let's rewrite the inequality above as:

\[ \bigg( \dfrac{1 + \dfrac{1}{n+1}}{ 1 + \dfrac{1}{n}} \bigg)^n > \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{n+1}}.
\]

The right-hand side equals

\[ \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{n+1}} = \dfrac{n+1}{n+2} = 1 - \dfrac{1}{n+2}.
\]

Now, let's focus on the left-hand side:

\[ \bigg( \dfrac{1 + \dfrac{1}{n+1}}{ 1 + \dfrac{1}{n}} \bigg)^n = \bigg( \dfrac{(n+2)/(n+1)}{(n+1)/n} \bigg)^n = \bigg( \dfrac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2} \bigg)^n = \bigg( 1 - \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}\bigg)^n.
\]

By the Bernoulli's inequality, the following holds:

\[ \bigg( 1 - \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}\bigg)^n \geq 1 - \dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2}
\]

Now it's purely technical to show the desired inequality

\[ 1 - \dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2} > 1 - \dfrac{1}{n+2},
\]

because

\[ \dfrac{n}{(n+1)^2} < \dfrac{1}{n+2}.
\]

Comment: @Chris'ssister: In my Calculus course (at least) Bernoulli's inequality is an example of proof by induction. No calculus methods needed!

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: actually, you're right.