# Show that a sequence is bounded by $3$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hey I'm supposed to show that the sequence $a_n=(1+\dfrac{1}{n})^n < 3$.
Can someone please help me out?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view , pages 99-100.

Comment: It's informed that the limit is equal to e. But is it sufficient to argue that the sequence must be less than 3?

Comment: @HansLundmark That answer already assumes $e$ is defined. Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185660/prove-1-frac1nn-is-bounded-above) is more appropriate.