# Finding limit of $\left(1 +\frac1x\right)^x$ without using L'Hôpital's rule.

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Is there a way to find this limit without using L'Hôpital's rule. Just by using some basic limit properties.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=e$$

Comment: How do you define $e$?

Comment: What tools do you have available?

Comment: This is one of the ways of defining $e$.  You can see the proof of the equivalence of the various definitions at [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Euler%27s_Number).

Comment: A reasonable interpretation of the question would be, how do you prove that the natural log of the given limit equals 1, where the natural log function is defined as an integral of 1/t dt? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty}{x \choose k}{1 \over x^{k}} = {1 \over k!}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We may show that
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} x\left(\log(x+1)-\log(x)\right) = 1 \tag{1}$$
by noticing that
$$ x\left(\log(x+1)-\log(x)\right)=\int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{x}{t}\,dt \tag{2}$$
is trivially bounded between $\frac{x}{x+1}$ and $1$, since $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Wow, this is slick.  I don't think I've ever seen limits evaluated by bounding an equivalent integral..

Answer (score 1):

In the comments it has been pointed out that this usually serves as a definition of e.  But I think I know what you're asking.  Usually in introductory calculus classes to evaluate this limit you let $$y= \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x,$$ and then take the natural log of both sides to get $$\ln(y) = \lim_{x\to\infty} x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}},$$ where the last limit you use L'Hôpital's rule to get that it is equal to 1.  So I think maybe what you are actually asking is can, $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ be evaluated without L'Hôpital's rule?  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  If this is indeed your question you can expand $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ as a series at $x=\infty$ which I think makes the limit trivial.

I don't think I've ever used these kinds of power series so I would appreciate any input about this last suggestion.

Comment: Yes i've tried to say so. I should take a look at Taylor's series.

Comment: Taylor series are definitely really useful.  Jack's answer below is super cool and pretty elementary and shows the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two of my questions
which, combined,
answer your question:

[Is this proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ exists (1) new, (2) interesting?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387272/is-this-proof-that-lim-n-to-infty-11-nn-exists-1-new-2-interesti)

[Is showing $\lim_{z \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{z})^z$ exists the same as $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316713/is-showing-lim-z-to-infty-1-frac1zz-exists-the-same-as-lim-n)