# showing an inequality not using stirling formula

Tags: calculus

I don't know how to show that

$$
\frac{k^k}{k!}\leq e^{k}
$$

without using Stirling's approximation. I want to show it directly. I guess I need some inequality to achieve this but I don't know.

Comment: Can you use $$e^x = 1 + x  + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{x^k}{k!} + \cdots$$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Taylor series for $e^x$ is $$e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
so for an integer $k$ we have

$$e^k = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k^n}{n!} = 1+\frac{k}{1!}+\frac{k^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{k^k}{k!}+\cdots$$

If you don't want to use Taylor series, you could prove it with induction. All we'll need is the Binomial Theorem, some algebra skills, and a small (easy to verify) fact at the end.

Step one (starting with $k=1$):

$$e \geq 1$$

Great, let's proceed to the induction step, where we suppose that $e^k \geq \frac{k^k}{k!}$ for some (fixed) $k$ no less than $2$:

\begin{align}\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} &= \frac{(k+1)^k}{k!} \\ &= \frac{\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}k^{k-i}}{k!} \\ &= \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{1}{k!}\binom{k}{i}k^{k-i} \\ &= \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{k^{k-i}}{i!(k-i)!} \\
&= \frac{k^k}{k!}+\frac{k^{k-1}}{1!(k-1)!}+\frac{k^{k-2}}{2!(k-2)!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k!} \\ &\leq e^k+\frac{e^{k-1}}{1!}+\frac{e^{k-2}}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k!} \\ &< e^k + e^{k-1} + \cdots + 1\end{align}

The last sum can be shown to be less than $e^{k+1}$ provided you can show that, for all real numbers $a \geq 2$, the inequality $a^{n+1} > a^n+a^{n-1}+\cdots+a+1$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

A short proof of that last claim, for those interested:

> One can easily show that $a^n+a^{n-1}+\cdots+a+1 = \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$. Let $\alpha = \frac{1}{a-1}$. Then $a \geq 2 \Rightarrow 0 < \alpha \leq 1 \Rightarrow \alpha a^{n+1} \leq a^{n+1} \Rightarrow \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1} = \alpha(a^{n+1}-1) < a^{n+1}$ since $\alpha(a^{n+1}-1) < \alpha a^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 11):

If you want a somewhat elementary argument not using Taylor series, I have one that only relies on the fact that for any $x>0$ we have $\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^x < e$ (which is proved by showing $\ln(x+1)-\ln(x) < \frac{1}{x}$ using integration).

Then we have
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{k^k}{k!} 
& = \left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)^{k-1}
\left(\frac{k-1}{k-2}\right)^{k-2}
\left(\frac{k-2}{k-3}\right)^{k-3}\cdots
\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^3
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2
\left(\frac{2}{1}\right)\\
& < e \cdot e \cdot e \cdots \cdots e \cdot e \cdot e
= e^{k-1} < e^k \end{align*}
$$

Comment: I guess this is the shortest one. Thanks!

Comment: This is the weak form of Stirling inequality used to prove [Carleman's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_inequality#Proof) , so that is more elementary than I thought.

Answer (score 4):

Both sides of the inequality are positive. So log both sides, and prove $k\ln k-\ln(k!)\le k$ :
$$\ln(k!)=\sum_{i=2}^k\ln i\ge\sum_{i=2}^k\int_{i-1}^i\ln x\,dx=\int_1^k\ln x\,dx=\left[x\ln x - x\right]_1^k =(k\ln k-k)-(-1)\ge k\ln k-k
$$

Answer (score 3):

And yet another approach. First note that for $n>k$
$$ \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)=\frac{n}{n}\frac{n-1}{n}\ldots\frac{n-k+1}{n}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}\rightarrow 1\tag{1}$$
when $n\rightarrow\infty$ because $k$ is fixed and each term of the product converges to 1.

Therefore, since you know that (by the binomial expansion)
\begin{align} \left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^n&=1+\binom{n}{1}\frac{k}{n}+\ldots+\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^k+\ldots+\binom{n}{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\\
&\ge \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^k \\
&=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} \left(\frac{k^k}{k!}\right)\end{align}
Taking limits on both sides you have (depends on what definition you have of $e^k$ but usually this is the most elementary)

$$ e^k=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\ge\left(\frac{k^k}{k!}\right)\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}=\left(\frac{k^k}{k!}\right)~~,$$
because of (1).

Comment: Thanks! This is also a good approach.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Suppose
$\frac{k^k}{k!}\leq e^{k}
$
and
$\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}> e^{k+1}
$.
Then
$e
=\frac{e^{k+1}}{e^{k}}
<\frac{\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{k^k}{k!}}
=(1+\frac1{k})^k
$.

But
$(1+\frac1{k})^k
< e
$,
as shown in many places
(including this question of mine:
[What is the most elementary proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389793/what-is-the-most-elementary-proof-that-lim-n-to-infty-11-nn-exists)).

Therefore,
$\frac{k^k}{k!}\leq e^{k}
\implies
\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}> e^{k+1}
$.
Since
$\frac{1^1}{1!}
< e^1
$,
$\frac{k^k}{k!}\leq e^{k}
$ for all $k$.

Comment: Thank you! Another smart way to show it.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat different approach:

In the pmf for a Poisson$(k)$ $P(X=k) = \frac{e^{-k} k^k}{k!}$ but $P(X=k)<1$ (since it's a probability).

The result follows by multiplying by $e^k$.

Comment: COOL. Thanks! Probability method. But I guess to show it is a probability we need to show this inequality.

Comment: Proofs designed for humans necessarily take some things as "given" (assumed knowledge). This relies on already having the Poisson as a distribution as "given"; whether that's acceptable depends on who you're talking to. If I'm talking to another statistician, this is a good short proof, of the form I generally call "spot the density". [To show $\frac{e^{-k}k^k}{k!}\leq 1$, however, you only need $\exp(-k)x^k/x!\geq 0$ (for all non-negative integer $x$) and that $\sum_{x=0}^\infty x^k/x!=e^k$  $\implies\sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{-k}x^k/x!=1$; whence they're *all* probabilities]

Comment: Okay. I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$e^x
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$,
for $x > 0$
and any integer $n$,
$e^x
> \frac{x^n}{n!}
$.

Setting $x = n$,
$e^n
> \frac{n^n}{n!}
$.