# Proof? of the limit$ \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} = e $

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

we do know the formula for e:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} = e $$
I was hoping to prove it using LH. Assume we don't know the value
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} = x $$
Then we can use logarithms to solve this and since $$ \ln(x) $$ is continuous everywhere we can write
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}n \ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) = \ln x $$
apply LH:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}  = \ln x $$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n})}\frac{-1}{n^2}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}  = \ln x $$
this simplifies to
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} = \ln x $$
which we can evaluate to 
$$ \frac {1}{1+0} = 1 = \ln x$$
Therefore we come at
$$ \ln x = 1 $$
$$x=e$$
What I'm wondering about is whether i am actually able to use the natural logarithm because i assume i don't know what 'e' is. Is this actually validor i have to take the limit purely as a definition of the euler number?

Comment: Yeah, but when i use the fact, that the derivative of a logarithm whose base is unknown, is 1/n... is invalid, isn't it?

Comment: But that limit isn't $e$...

Comment: Oh, messed that up :S Corrected it now

Comment: Yup, had my formulation of the limit wrong. There had to be + sign instead of -. Now everything should be correct.

Comment: What is your definition of the euler number $\mathrm{e}$? And what is your definition of $\ln$?

Comment: That limit is usually (at least the way I learned things) taken as the definition of $e$. You can, however, prove that the sequence $a_{n} = (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is convergent, by proving that it's increasing and bounded. I remember that the proof was not easy for me as a beginner, so it might be worth your time. Of course, you can also take $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$ as the definition of $e$, provided you know some basic things about series first.

Comment: The limit as you've stated is usually the definition of $e$. Therefore this question cannot be answered unless you provide your own definition of $e$

Answer (score 2):

A person can define $\ln(x)$ and prove its derivative is $1/x$, etc, without knowing anything about  $(1+1/n)^n$:

For $x>0$ define $$\ln(x)=\int_1^x\frac{dt}t.$$

It follows that $\ln'(x)=1/x$. Hence $\ln$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$. And it's clear that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln(x)=\int_0^1\frac{dt}t=\infty.$$Similarly $\lim_{x\to0}\ln(x)=-\infty$.

So $\ln$ is a strictly increasing differentiable bijection from $(0,
\infty)$ onto $\mathbb R$. So it has a strictly increasing differentiable inverse. *Define* $\exp:\mathbb R\to(0,\infty)$ to be the inverse of $\ln$. *Define* $e=\exp(1)$.

Note that $$\ln(xy)=\int_1^x\frac{dt}t+\int_x^{xy}\frac{dt}t=\int_1^x\frac{dt}t+\int_1^y\frac{dt}t=\ln(x)+\ln(y),$$by a simple  substitution in the last integral. Hence $\ln(x^n)=n\ln(x)$ by induction; hence $\exp(nx)=\exp(x)^n$.

Now you don't even need L'Hopital, just the definition of the derivative shows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln(1+1/n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+1/n)-\ln(1)}{1/n}=\ln'(1)=1/1=1.$$ Since $\exp$ is the inverse of $\ln$ and $\exp$ is continuous this shows that $$\lim(1+1/n)^n=\lim\exp(n\ln(1+1/n))=\exp(1)=e$$.

Answer (score 1):

All of the objects involved here ($e, \ln x$, etc.) have several equivalent definitions and it takes some interesting work to prove that they're all equivalent; until you do questions like "how do I prove X" are ambiguous because they might be easy using some definitions and hard using others (before you've proven that they're all equivalent).

For example, you can define $\ln x$ without knowing what $e$ is, by defining it as the integral

$$\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}.$$

Using this integral you can prove the fundamental properties that $\ln (ab) = \ln a + \ln b$ and also that $\ln (1 + x) \approx x$ for $x$ small, which is enough to run your proof. Now you can define $e^x$ as the inverse of $\ln x$, if you want.

---

My preferred way to prove all of these equivalences is to start from the definition that $e^x$ is the unique function $f(x)$ satisfying $f(0) = 1$ and $f'(x) = f(x)$. From here, you can show that

$$e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^n$$

by showing that this limit defines a function $g(x)$ which also satisfies $g(0) = 1$ and $g'(x) = x$; hence it must be equal to $e^x$, and now you can plug in $x = 1$. This identity can be interpreted as using [Euler's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) with smaller and smaller step sizes to approximate the solution to $f'(x) = f(x)$.

Generally speaking it's much nicer to prove things about $e^x$ rather than $e$, and arguably it is by far the more fundamental object.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph. Often this is not mentioned in elementary calculus textbooks and leads to ample confusion in the minds of beginners in calculus.

Answer (score 1):

I supplied an
elementary proof
(not my own)
 that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$
exists here:

[What is the most elementary proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389793/what-is-the-most-elementary-proof-that-lim-n-to-infty-11-nn-exists)

$e$ is then the name of that limit.

Once you know 
that the limit exists
you can then do
a variety of things
to show that it is the same
as your definition of $e$.