# (1+z/n)^n for complex z is not uniformly convergent to exp(z) on C

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, exponential-function

why is the sequence not uniformly convergent on the whole C?
Can one show, that sup(f_n-f) is unequal zero?
Thanks

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to be uniformly continuous?

Comment: I am sorry. I have corrected the question

Comment: $|e^z-(1+z/n)^n|$ is unbounded on $\Bbb C$ for all $n$. In fact it's unbounded on $\Bbb R$: exponentials dominate polynomials.

Comment: thank you artic tern!
why is it unbounded?

Comment: We have $\exp(x)>x^n/n!$ for all naturals $n$ and positive reals $x$. (Just look at the power series defining $\exp$ after all.) You can use this to prove $\exp(x)-f(x)$ is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$ for any polynomial $f(x)$.

Comment: but isn't the limit of(1+z/n)^n exactly e(z)? so the distance between them is getting less and less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to show that the convergence is not uniform on $\mathbb{R}$. We need to show that $(1+z/n)^n$ does not converge too fast to $e^z$. We should also know that $(1+z/n)^n$ is increasing for $z\geq 0$ (see [I have to show $(1+\frac1n)^n$ is monotonically increasing sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/i-have-to-show-1-frac1nn-is-monotonically-increasing-sequence) and [planetmath](http://planetmath.org/node/8649)), so we have to show that $e^z-(1+z/n)^n$ is not too small, for a given $n$, when $z$ is very large.

Take $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Take $k\geq 0$ and $z=kn$. Then
$$\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n=(1+k)^n=\sum_{j=1}^n n(n-1)\cdots (n-j+1)\frac{k^j}{j!}\geq n^j\frac{k^j}{j!}=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{z^j}{j!}$$
Also, $e^z=\sum_{j=1}^\frac{z^j}{j!}$, so
$$e^z-(1+z/n)^n\geq\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty \frac{z^j}{j!}\geq\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
If $k$ is very large, then $\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ is also very large. This shows that for all $\epsilon>0$ (and in particular there exists *some* $\epsilon>0$) such that for all $n$, there exists $z$ with $|e^z-(1+z/n)^n|>\epsilon$. This is the negation of uniform convergence.

Answer (score 0):

I will show,
using only
$\ln(1+z)
=\int_0^z \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
$,
that,
if $0 < z < n$
then
$z-\ln (1+z/n)^n
=c\dfrac{z^{2}}{2n}
$
where $\frac12 < c < 1$.

Therefore
if $z = n/2$,
$z-\ln (1+z/n)^n
=c\dfrac{(n/2)^{2}}{2n}
=cn/8
$
so that
the convergence is not uniform.

Here we go.

Since,
for positive integer $m$,
$\dfrac1{1+v}
=\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} (-1)^k v^k+\dfrac{v^{2m}}{1+v}
$,
integrating,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+v)
&=\int_0^v \dfrac{dw}{1+w}\\
&=\int_0^v(\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} (-1)^k w^k+\dfrac{w^{2m}}{1+w})dw\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} \dfrac{(-1)^k v^{k+1}}{k+1}+\int_0^v\dfrac{w^{2m}}{1+w}dw
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
z-\ln (1+z/n)^n
&=z-n\ln (1+z/n)\\
&=z-n(\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} \dfrac{(-1)^k (z/n)^{k+1}}{k+1}+\int_0^{z/n}\dfrac{w^{2m}}{1+w}dw)\\
&=z-\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} \dfrac{(-1)^k z^{k+1}}{n^k(k+1)}
-n\int_0^{z/n}\dfrac{w^{2m}}{1+w}dw)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2m-1} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1} z^{k+1}}{n^k(k+1)}
-\int_0^{z}\dfrac{(w/n)^{2m}}{1+w/n}dw\\
\end{array}
$

If
$0 < z < 1$,
$1-z
\lt \frac1{1+z}
\lt 1-z/2
$,
so
$\frac1{1+z}
=1-cz
$
where
$\frac12 < c < 1$.

Therefore,
if $n > z$,

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^{z}\dfrac{(w/n)^{2m}}{1+w/n}dw
&=\int_0^{z}(1-cw/n)(w/n)^{2m}dw\\
&=\int_0^{z}((w/n)^{2m}-c(w/n)^{2m+1})dw\\
&=\dfrac{z^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)n^{2m}}-c\dfrac{z^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)n^{2m+1}}\\
\end{array}
$

so that

$\begin{array}\\
z-\ln (1+z/n)^n
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2m-1} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1} z^{k+1}}{n^k(k+1)}
-\int_0^{z}\dfrac{(w/n)^{2m}}{1+w/n}dw\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2m-1} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1} z^{k+1}}{n^k(k+1)}
-(\dfrac{z^{2m+1}}{(2m+1)n^{2m}}-c\dfrac{z^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)n^{2m+1}})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2m} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1} z^{k+1}}{n^k(k+1)}
+c\dfrac{z^{2m+2}}{(2m+2)n^{2m+1}}\\
\end{array}
$

If $m=0$,
this is
$z-\ln (1+z/n)^n
=c\dfrac{z^{2}}{2n}
$.

If $m=1$,
this is
$z-\ln (1+z/n)^n
=\dfrac{ z^{2}}{2n}
-\dfrac{ z^{3}}{3n^2}
+c\dfrac{z^{4}}{4n^3}
$.

In particular,
when $m=0$,
if $z = n/2$,
$z-\ln (1+z/n)^n
=c\dfrac{(n/2)^{2}}{2n}
=cn/8
$.