# How can I prove $\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^{n}\le\left(1+{1\over 1+n}\right)^{n+1}$ via induction?

Tags: inequality, induction

I am trying to prove this:
$$\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^{n}\le\left(1+{1\over 1+n}\right)^{n+1}$$

I tried to prove by changing the main problem for a more general one , namely: $$a^{n}\le b^{n+1}$$ for $a$ and $b$ integers $>1$ and $a \le b$. Then by induction I tried to prove that (an induction on the three variables $a, b$ and $n$). For base case I chose $n=1 , b=2$ and $ a=3. $
After that I used bernouilli to get from  $$(a+1)^{n+1}\le(b+1)^{n+2}$$ to $$1+a(n+1)\le 1+b(n+2)$$
then removing $1$ : $$a(n+1)\le b(n+2)$$ and after development $$an+a \le bn+2b$$
notice that $$a \le bn+b$$ si true then we can remove it and get $$an\le bn+2b$$
there is where I was stuck
Thank you for anyone who could help me prove it with induction or by a simpler manner

Comment: Your "more general" problem would not imply the result you want since $1 + 1/n \ge 1 + 1/(n+1)$ and also these quantities are not integers when $n > 1$.

Comment: What do you suggest I should do to prove it then ?

Comment: Oh just noticed I made a mistake while typing, I meant $b\le a$ not the opposite.

Comment: You can find two proofs *without* induction in the answers to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515317/how-is-a-n-11-nn-monotonically-increasing-and-bounded-by-3/4452536#4452536

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\left(1+\frac1{n}\right)^{n}&lt;\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$ by mathematical induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089515/prove-left1-frac1n-rightn-left1-frac1n1-rightn1-by-mathema) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D)%5En%5Cle(1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D)%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainduction&p=1). Note there are also quite a few other questions, and answers, here about proving the same inequality, but not necessarily using induction, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [Proving : $\bigl(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\bigr)^{n+1} \gt (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$](/q/64860), [Prove the inequality $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$](/q/3302120), [Showing the exponential sequence is strictly increasing](/q/2324662), [Show that $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is monotonically increasing](/q/167843), [Arithmetic and Geometric Mean Inequality](/q/563096), [The function $f(n)=(1+1/n)^{n+1}$ is decreasing](/q/2071492), etc. There are also related AoPS threads, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [(1+1/n)^n](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h86413p503885). Finally, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help ! It was indeed very helpful ! Have a nice day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\left(1+{1\over 1+n}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^{n}}=
\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right)^{n+1}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n}>\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1} \right)\cdot \frac{n+1}{n}=1$$

Comment: Thank you so much that was the type of proof I was looking for concise, even if I'd wish you développed more but I think I can do it myself thank you so much again for your help !

Comment: Glad to be helpful. If you think this is the answer to your question, then you can select it.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative Proof**

Consider $$f(x)=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x$$
$$f'=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\left((x+1)\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-1\right)}{x+1}$$
$$f'(x)>0 \implies 
\\
x>0$$
Since all natural numbers are $\ge0$ it will be an increasing function on that domain.

---

Another way is to use the expansion of the above mentioned function.

Comment: That a very intresting approach to the problem thank you so much for your help !