# Determine if $\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$ is monotone

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to show that 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{n^n}{n!e^n} 
\end{eqnarray}
whether it is decreasing or increasing sequences or neither.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\frac{1}{e}$.

Since $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=1$

What can we say about the sequences according to $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=1$.

Can we say it is neither decreasing nor increasing ? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, what you have so far is not enough to settle it.

Comment: We can't say anything about increasing our decreasing from that limit. Have you calculated the first three or four terms to get a feel for the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $(1+\frac 1 n)^n$  [is increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/i-have-to-show-1-frac1nn-is-monotonically-increasing-sequence) and $\lim (1+\frac1n)^n = e$ therefore $(1+\frac1n)^n \lt e$ and $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} \lt 1$

Answer (score 2):

The sequence is **non-increasing**. Before proving it, first: *compute the first terms, it will help you check whether your intuition is correct!*

On `Mathematica` or [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DiscretePlot%5B+n%5En%2F(n!+E%5En),+%7Bn,+1,+100%7D%5D&t=crmtb01):

> DiscretePlot[ n^n/(n! E^n), {n, 1, 100}][[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFgKA.png)

Then, once you have done that and gotten a sense of what you have to prove (here: the sequence, if anything, does look decreasing) you can attempt to prove it.

Let $a_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{n^n}{n!e^n}$. Then it is easy to see that
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = e\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n
= \frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}
$$
Now, from $$
(1+\frac{1}{n})^n = e^{n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})} \leq e^{n\cdot \frac{1}{n}} =e^1 =e
$$
(which follows from the standard inequality  $\ln(1+x)\leq x$) we get
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \geq 1
$$
for all $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a(n) = n^n/(n! e^n)$, then

$$ \eqalign{\ln \left( \frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)} \right) &= n \log(1+1/n) - 1\cr
&= -\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{3n^2} - \frac{1}{4n^3} + \ldots}$$
I claim this is negative.  Indeed, 
for $n \ge 1$, $$-\frac{1}{2m n^{2m}} + \frac{1}{(2m+1)n^{2m+1}} < 0 $$
Thus $a(n+1)/a(n) < 1$, and the sequence is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

If $n!\sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$, then:

$$\frac{n^n}{n!e^n}=\frac{1}{n!} \cdot \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sim \left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}} \cdot \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$
which is decreasing.