# How to prove that $\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n < \left(1+\frac 1 {n+1}\right)^{n+1}$?

Tags: inequality

How would one prove the following:$$\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n < \left(1+\frac 1 {n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$

This is taken from the book challenge and thrill of precollege mathematics.

Comment: Is $n\in\Bbb N$? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

One sledgehammer approach is to use calculus to verify that $x \ln(1+1/x)$ is monotonically increasing with $x>0.$

Comment: Perhaps this problem is intended as a pre-log exercise?

Comment: Probably, that's why I called it a sledgehammer approach. There are plenty of nice elementary solutions available at the link given by dromastyx.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to showing that $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is monotonically increasing. Here are many proofs:

[I have to show $(1+\frac1n)^n$ is monotonically increasing sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/i-have-to-show-1-frac1nn-is-monotonically-increasing-sequence)

Comment: A comment would have sufficed.