# Bernoulli inequality and Exponential Bound

Tags: calculus

I'm asking a complete proof of the Exponential Bound using the Bernoulli Inequality.

Exponential bound:

$$1+x\leq e^x$$

Bernoulli inequality

$$1+nx\leq\left(1+x\right)^n$$
for all
$$x>= -1$$
and
$$n=1,2,...$$

[Here](https://jeremykun.com/2015/11/23/the-inequality/) it's a partial (x>=0) proof but lacks the most interesting part, when x<0.

Comment: I don't understand why the hypothesis of  X >= -1 is needed

Comment: @chess4ever when x<1 the inequality is obvious: x<-1 =>  1+x<0<=e^x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Bernoulli inequality with $\;\frac xn\;$ instead of $\;x\,$ , and $\;x>-1\;$ (otherwise it is very simple...) :

$$1+x\stackrel{\text{Bernoulli}}\le\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\le e^x$$

because the central expression is a monotonic ascendent sequence whose limit is $\;e^x\;$ .

Comment: this is such a beatiful proof !
And to prove that it's  monotonic ascendent we can use Bernoulli again !
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/i-have-to-show-1-frac1nn-is-monotonically-increasing-sequence

Answer (score 3):

Note that

- for $x<-1\implies 1+x<0 \le e^x $
- for $x>-1$

$$e\ge \left(1+\frac1x\right)^x \implies e^x\ge \left(1+\frac1x\right)^{x^2}\implies e^x\ge 1+x^2\cdot\frac1x=1+x$$

Answer (score 0):

1.) The exponential bound is trivial for $x<-1$ so it keeps to show it for $x \ge -1$

2.) Consider that in the proof of the given link you can choose $z \ge -1$ instead of $z\ge 0$ and the proof is still valid...

And you are done.