# Compute limit of a sequence of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I cannot compute

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^2\left(1+\frac{\ln x}{n}\right)^n \,\mathrm{d}x.$$

The reason is that I cannot find an antiderivative for $(1+\frac{\ln x}{n})^n $,
or, I cannot see if the sequence $\{(1+\frac{\ln x}{n})^n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ is uniformly convergent.

What should we do to find the limit in this case?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Yes, but what about the uniform convergence?

Comment: If you use LDC, you do not need uniform convergence, only pointwise almost-everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that for every $x \in [1,2]$,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{\ln x}{n}\right)^n  = e^{\ln x} =x.$$
This limit is [increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/i-have-to-show-1-frac1nn-is-monotonically-increasing-sequence), so that all the functions $f_n(x) := \left(1+\frac{\ln x}{n}\right)^n$ are bounded from above by $f(x) := x$ on $[1,2]$.
We also have pointwise convergence $f_n \to f$ on $[1,2]$, so that by [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem),

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_1^2 f_n(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \int_1^2 f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \int_1^2 x\, \mathrm{d}x = \tfrac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: I think we do not need even to know that the sequence $\{(1+\frac{lnx}{n})^n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is increasing, because note that on $[1,2]$, $lnx\leq lne=1$, so $(1+\frac{lnx}{n})^n\leq (1+\frac{1}{n})^n \leq e$ and we can take the function $f$ as $f(x):=e$ on $[1,2]$. But, of course we should know that the sequence  $\{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is increasing.

Comment: @serenus You're still using that $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing in $n$ if you want to bound it by $e$ for all $n$. Though indeed it is not strictly necessary that it be increasing; the functions $f_n$ just need to be bounded by some integrable function on $[1,2]$. The fact that the limit is increasing just made the argument even simpler: we can bound them by their (pointwise) limit.