# Induction on $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis

$$(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n \geq 2$$

Base base: $n = 1$

LHS: $(1+ 1)^1 \leq 2$  RHS: 2

$2 \leq 2$ True.

Inductive step:

$$(1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} \geq 2$$

$$(1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^n (1 + \frac{1}{n+1}) \geq 2$$

Im stuck

Comment: just use binomial expansion to prove the inequality

Comment: we barely went over that. How would that look?

Comment: this might be useful $\frac{1}{n} > \frac{1}{n+1}$,

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/show-that-left1-dfrac1n-rightn-is-monotonically-increasing

Comment: @K.Gibson $(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}=1^{n+1}+(n+1)1^{n}\frac{1}{n+1}+ ... + (\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}=2+ \ some \ positive \ number$

Comment: I was able to use the binomial expansion

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality):
$$
(1+x)^n \ge 1 + nx \quad \mbox{for $x\ge 0$}
$$
This can be proved by induction.