# For a natural number k prove that 2(kᵏ) < (k+1)ᵏ

Tags: inequality, induction

> For a natural number k prove that 2(kᵏ) < (k+1)ᵏ
>
> > I encountered this inequality while encountering an induction problem that stated
> > 2ⁿ.n! < nⁿ
> > For the induction step i chose 6 which satisfies
> > Assume for some positive k>6
> > 2ᵏ.k! < kᵏ ...(1)
> > holds true then we must show that

2ᵏ+¹.(k+1)! < (k+1)ᵏ+¹ follows from (1)
multiplying eq(1) by 2.(k+1) on both side which results in
2ᵏ+¹.(k+1)! < 2kᵏ.(k+1)

> > If we can show that 2kᵏ< (k+1)ᵏ then it will complete the proof. CAN SOMEONE HELP

Comment: Try, for example, $n=10$.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1+\frac 1x\right)^6=1$.

Comment: Hm, do you lost factorial in first line?

Comment: it is all correct my friend

Comment: The claim in your header is clearly false, as has been pointed out to you...so something is off.  The body of your post speaks about factorials and has $n$ in an exponent, so it looks very different from the question in your header.

Comment: $2n^6 < (n+1)^6 \iff 2 < \frac {(n+1)^6}{n^6}=(1+\frac 1n)^6\iff \sqrt[6] 2 < 1+\frac 1n\iff \sqrt[6]2-1 < \frac 1n\iff n < \frac 1{\sqrt[6]2 -1} \approx 8.165$ so for $n \ge 9$ this will not be true. [$1062882= 2\cdot 9^6 > 10^6= 1000000$ for example]

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "on further solving at last i encountered the inequality 2(n⁶) < (n+1)⁶"  How????

Comment: Why are you keep changing the question?

Comment: This post (once corrected some more) will be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding your problem,you are saying $2x^x<(x+1)^x$ when x > 1 and x a natural number.

Well if you expand the right hand side by the binomial theorem, you get $(x+1)^x=x^x+x\times x^{x-1}+C_x^2\times x^{x-2}+...$

Just taking the first two terms in the expantion gives you $(x+1)^x>2x^x$

Actually you can also prove this by derivatives

The original is equivalent to $2<(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$

Now let's prove that $((1+\frac{1}x)^x)'$ is bigger than zero when x is positive

It turns out that the above is equal to $e^{x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\left(-\frac{1}{x+1}+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$

The exponential part on the left is bigger than zero,so we just need to prove that $-\frac{1}{x+1}+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)>0$.This can be seen easily by taking another derivative.

Comment: Thank you very much if you can explain the derivative method it will be good

Comment: @user4372 I put it in the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what you are trying to say, but $2k^k < (k+1)^k; k \in \mathbb{N}$ can be disproven without induction by providing the counterexample $k = 1 \Rightarrow 2 \times1^1 = (1+1)^1 $.