# series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}$$

I tried Abel, Dirichlet theorems and it seems like divergent series but I don’t know the series a can compare to (for proving of divergence)

//i’m sorry that I can’t post images cuz due to reputation, this is my first question :>

Comment: Please use MathJax to type your equations.

Comment: Is your series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n\cdot\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}$?

Comment: since $\dfrac{e}{3} \lt 1$, I would expect this series to converge

Comment: @coreyman317 yes it is

Comment: The sum of the series seems to be slightly less than $6.22513$

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

to find $$\dfrac13\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^n=\dfrac e3<1$$

Comment: Thanks so much, i forgot to put 1/n to 1/3 :D

Comment: It is not necessary for the proof of convergence but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}/3^n}{e^n/3^n} =  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$

Answer (score 0):

$0 < (1/3)^n[(1+1/n)^n]^n <$

$(1/3)^ne^n=(e/3)^n=:a^n$, where $a<1$.

$\sum a^n$ is convergent, now use comparison test.

Used: $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing, bounded from above by $e$.

Recall: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+1/n)^n=e.$

[Show that $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is monotonically increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/show-that-left1-dfrac1n-rightn-is-monotonically-increasing)