# How to show that $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ monotonic growing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, eulers-number-e

I have to show that

$a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

is monotonic increasing. I struggle alot and tryng to find a right form to epxress that,

$a_n\le a_{n+1}$

a little hint what might help would be great. Im in my first year in the introduction to real analysis, so tipps with derivative or more advanced arent usefull :/

I really only like to get a little hint :)

Comment: $$a_n \le a_{n+1} \iff (n+1)^{2n+1} \le n^n(n+2)^{n+1} \iff \frac{n+1}{n+2} \le \left( 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right)^n$$ Besides, $$\left( 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right)^n \ge 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}n $$ and clearly $$1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}n \ge 1-\frac{1}{n+2}$$ Done.

Comment: Try and show that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geq1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\left( 1+ \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^{n+1}}{\left( 1+ \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}}=\frac{n+1}{n}\left( 1- \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right)^{n+1}>\\
>\frac{n+1}{n}\left( 1- \frac{1}{(n+1)} \right)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ f(x)=(1+\frac1x)^x $$
and show $f(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: Is this possible without the derivative? And is n fixed here?

Comment: $n$ should be $x$. Sorry about that. Let me think about without derivative.

Comment: See the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/show-that-left1-dfrac1n-rightn-is-monotonically-increasing