# Show that for natural $n \ge 2$ :$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}>1-\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: inequality

Show that for natural $n \ge 2$ the following does hold:

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}>1-\frac{1}{n}$$

---

First solution:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}>1-\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\iff$$
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}>1-\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}>1$$

By Bernoulli inequality:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\ge2\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n}\right)=\frac{2}{n}$$

Which is not useful.

Second solution:

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\ge0\cdot2=0$$

Which is not useful.

Third solution:

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\ge2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}=\left(1+\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^{n-1}$$$$\ge1-\frac{n-1}{2}=\frac{3-n}{2}$$

Final solution:

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}>1-\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\iff$$
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)>1$$
By Bernoulli inequality:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)>1-\frac{n-1}{n^{2}}=1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\ge\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}$$

Which is true to claim that $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}>1-\frac{1}{n}$$
Since for natural $n \ge 2$ we have that $$\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right)>\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Have you tried Binomial expansion? $n\geq 2$, so $|\frac1{n^2}| < 1.$

Comment: I would try induction...

Comment: Your first approach is equivalent to: $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}>\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @masaheb Yeah that's my point.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/show-that-left1-dfrac1n-rightn-is-monotonically-increasing).

Comment: Why did you delete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4140658/use-the-general-formula-to-show-that-deltan-f-i-nhn/4140665#4140665) after I posted an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Show that for natural $n \ge 2$ the following does hold:
> $$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}>1-\frac{1}{n}$$

By using the Bernoulli’s inequality

$(1+x)^{n}>1+nx$

for any natural $\;n\ge2\;$ and for any $\;x>-1\;,$

with $\;x=-\dfrac1{n^2}>-1\;,\;$

we get that

$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{n}>1+n\left(-\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)=1-\dfrac1n\;,$

for any natural $\;n\ge2\;.$

Comment: Beat me to it...