# I need help to prove this inequality, I'm not really sure what the question means.

Tags: inequality, algebras

**Question**

Let n be a positive integer and $x>y$. Prove that
$$\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}>ny^{n-1}$$
By choosing suitable values of x and y, further prove than
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$
and
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}>\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}$$

**Answer**

From this I can prove $$\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}>ny^{n-1}$$
By Using $$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+y^{n-1})$$
I can get $$\frac{x^n-y^n}{x-y}=\frac{(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+y^{n-1})}{x-y}=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+y^{n-1}>y^{n-1}+y^{n-2}*y+...+y^{n-1}=y^{n-1}+y^{n-1}+...+y^{n-1}=ny^{n-1}$$

But after this, I'm not sure what to do for the next question.
Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2497586

Comment: And for the 2nd inequality of the same "next question": https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306186

Comment: Ty @AnneBauval for your help