# how to prove that $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$ is decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please, help me to prove that $$x_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$decreases.
I know I must to prove that that $$\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}> 1$$

What to do next?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/306178). It is also shown [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245) that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is an increasing sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write out 
$$
   \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^2}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3} \left( \frac{1+\frac{2}{n}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^2} \right)^n = 
\frac{\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^2}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3} \left( 1 - \frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^2} \right)^n = 
\frac{\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^2}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\left(n+1 \right)^2} \right)^n = \left(1+\frac{n}{(n+1)^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^3} \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\left(n+1 \right)^2} \right)^n
$$
we now have to use $(1-x)^n \leqslant \frac{1}{1+n x}$ for $0<x<1$ and $n \geqslant 1$:
$$
  \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \leqslant \frac{1+\frac{n}{(n+1)^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}}{ 1+\frac{n}{(n+1)^2} } < 1
$$

Comment: Sasha, we have $x_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$ and $x_{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+2}$. From this, how can I get $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^2}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^3} \left( \frac{1+\frac{2}{n}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^2} \right)^n$ ?

Comment: $$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{(n+2)^{n+2} \cdot n^{n+1}}{ (n+1)^{n+2} \cdot (n+1)^{n+1}} = \frac{\left(1+\frac{2}{n} \right)^{n+2} \cdot n^{n+2} \cdot n^{n+1}}{ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+2} \cdot n^{n+2} \cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} \cdot n^{n+1}}  $$ Now simplify and regroup.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x+1}$. In the following, we show that $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x>0$. We have $f(x) = \exp[(x+1)\log(1+\frac{1}{x})]$ and it is thus sufficient to show that $g(x) = (x+1)\log(1+\frac{1}{x})$ is decreasing. Indeed, $$g'(x) = \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) - \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x} = 0,$$
as $\log(1+y)<y,\,\forall y> 0$.

Comment: Usually one studies this sequence in order to introduce the exponential function and its inverse, the logarithm. Decreasing of this sequence can be proven by more elementary methods. The book "Analysis by its history" starts this way.

Answer (score 1):

This can be shown using AM $\ge$ GM or using Bernoulli's ineqaulity.

**1) Using AM $\ge$ GM**

Take one copy of $1$, and $n$ copies of $1 - \frac{1}{n}$, ($n \gt 1$) to get

$$ \frac{1 + n(1 - \frac{1}{n})}{n+1} \gt \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n/(n+1)}$$

which simplies to

$$ \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} \gt \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$$

Taking the reciprocals, yields

$$ \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} \lt \left(1 + \frac{1}{n-1}\right)^n $$

**2) Using [(generalized) Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Generalization)**

$$(1 + x)^r \lt 1 + rx $$
 for the case when $x \gt -1$, $x \neq 0$, and $0 \lt r \lt 1 $

Here we set $x = -\frac{1}{n}$, $r = \frac{n}{n+1}$ and obtain the result easily.

---

For a similar problem and multiple proofs of that (including AM,GM and bernoulli's inequality), see: [Proving : $ \bigl(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\bigr)^{n+1} \gt (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64860/proving-bigl1-frac1n1-bigrn1-gt-1-frac1nn)

Comment: As far as I know, this was first done in 1951: N.S Mendelsohn, An application of a famous inequality, Amer. Math. Monthly 58 (1951), 563

Comment: @martycohen: Thank you for the reference!