# Is this proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ exists (1) new, (2) interesting?

Tags: limits, inequality

I was playing around,
and decided to see
if I could come up with
a proof that
 $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$$
exists
that was as
elementary as possible
in that it uses only
Bernoulli's inequality.

This is probably not new,
but I haven't seen it before.
If it is already here,
so be it.

Here it is.

Let
$p_n
=(1+1/n)^n
$.

\begin{align}
\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}
&=\frac{(1+1/(n+1))^{n+1}}{(1+1/n)^n}\\
&=\frac{((n+2)/(n+1))^{n+1}}{((n+1)/n)^n}\\
&=\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}n^n}{(n+1)^{2n+1}}\\
&=\frac{(n(n+2))^{n+1}}{n(n+1)^{2n+1}}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)(n(n+2))^{n+1}}{n(n+1)^{2n+2}}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{n}\left(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^{2}}\right)^{n+1}\\
&=\frac{n+1}{n}\left(\frac{n^2+2n}{n^2+2n+1}\right)^{n+1}\\
\end{align}

By the version of
Bernoulli's inequality
which states
$(1-\frac1{m})^n > 1-\frac{n}{m}$
if
$m > n$,

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n^2+2n}{n^2+2n+1}\right)^{n+1}
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2+2n+1}\right)^{n+1}\\
&>\left(1-\frac{n+1}{n^2+2n+1}\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{n}{n+1}
\end{align}

so
$$\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} 
\ >\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{n}{n+1}
= 1.
$$

Therefore,
$p_n$
is an increasing sequence.

Going the other way,
by Bernoulli's inequality,

\begin{align}
\left(\frac{n^2+2n+1}{n^2+2n}\right)^{n+1}
&=\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+2n}\right)^{n+1}\\
& > 1+\frac{n+1}{n^2+2n}\\
&=\frac{n^2+3n+1}{n^2+2n}
\end{align}

so

\begin{align}
\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}
&<\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{n^2+2n}{n^2+3n+1}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{n^2+3n+1}\\
&=\frac{n^2+3n+2}{n^2+3n+1}\\
&<\frac{n^2+3n+2}{n^2+3n}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{n(n+3)}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\frac{p_{n+m}}{p_n}
&=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{p_{n+k+1}}{p_{n+k}}\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{n(n+3)}\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{n+1}{n}\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{n+2}{n+3}\\
&=\frac{n+m}{n}\frac{n+2}{n+m+2}\\
&=\frac{n^2+n(m+2)+2m}{n^2+n(m+2)}\\
&=1+\frac{2m}{n^2+n(m+2)}\\
&<1+\frac{2m}{nm}\\
&=1+\frac{2}{n}
\end{align}

Therefore
$p_n$ is bounded above.

Since it is an increasing sequence,
it has a limit.

Note:
Here is a proof that
$(1-\frac1{m})^n >1-\frac{n}{m}$
if
$2 \le n \le m$.

It is true for $n=2$,
since
\begin{align}
(1-\frac1{m})^2
&=1-\frac{2}{m}+\frac1{m^2}\\
& > 1-\frac{2}{m}
\end{align}

If it is true for $n$,
and $n < m$,
then

\begin{align}
(1-\frac1{m})^{n+1}
&=(1-\frac1{m})^n (1-\frac1{m}) \\
&\ge(1-\frac{n}{m}) (1-\frac1{m}) \\
&=1-\frac{n+1}{m}+\frac{n}{m^2} \\
&>1-\frac{n+1}{m} \\
\end{align}

I find this an 
interesting proof by induction
since it holds
for any $m$
for a range of $n$ values,
rather than all $n$.

Comment: It is not new.  It is very well known and the limit is the natural base of logarithm, aka the Euler number, $\text{e}$.

Comment: Please point me to it. Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Representations.

Comment: @Batominovski I think he's only asking if the *proof* is new. I'm sure he already knew that the given expression is a characterization of $e$.

Comment: Hope you didn't find my edit too invasive. @Batominovski I second Quinn

Comment: I don't care if the equations are on the left or center. Is the math OK? Is this new and/or interesting? That is what I care about.

Comment: Related to the first part:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64860/proving-bigl1-frac1n1-bigrn1-gt-1-frac1nn

Comment: I was aware of that. Note that I commented.

Comment: The proof of the limit using only Bernoulli's inequality was one of the questions I was given in my undergraduate introduction to real analysis course.

Comment: correct but some errors in products... where is k in the three last product signs?