# Prove Inequality using Induction

Tags: number-theory, inequality, induction

I am stuck on the last step where I need to prove:
$$k^\frac{1}{k} > (k+1)^\frac{1}{k+1}$$

Please give me methods only involving induction. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean $k^1/k<(k+1)^1/(k+1)$? Both sides equal $1$.

Comment: Sorry edited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise both sides to $k(k+1)$ we get:

$k^{k+1} > (k+1)^k$

To prove:
$ k > (1 + \frac{1}{k})^k$

Assume true for $k = n$; and now consider the case $k = n+1$

Then $n + 1 > (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n + 1$

multiplying both sides with $(1 + \frac{1}{n})$ we get

$(n +1)(1 + \frac{1}{n}) = n + 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{n} > (1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n+1} + 1 + \frac{1}{n} > (1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} + 1 + \frac{1}{n}$

$\implies n + 1 > (1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}$

Comment: Very nice. Exactly what OP asked for and simpler than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can get $\log$ from each side of the inequality:
$$\frac{\log k}{k} > \frac{\log (k+1)}{k+1}$$

Then, we want to show that $f(x) = \frac{\log x}{x}$ is a decreasing function. 
As $f'(x) = \frac{1-\log x}{x^2}$ is less than zero for $x > 1$, Hence the proof is completed.

Answer (score 0):

I give a proof
by induction
using only Bernoulli's inequality
here:

[Is this proof that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^n$ exists (1) new, (2) interesting?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387272/is-this-proof-that-lim-n-to-infty-11-nn-exists-1-new-2-interesti)