# Application of L'Hôpital's rule to a definition of $\mathrm{e}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^ n    $$
So the problem above is giving me trouble, the answer key I was giving says it equals to $\mathrm{e}$, but I have no idea how to get a answer. I look at the problem and plug in infinity to see if the indeterminate form appears, but I cannot tell, since I get $$\left(1+\frac{1}{\infty}\right)^\infty$$ I guess the problem here is what does $$\frac{1}{\infty}$$ equal? I think it equals infinity. If that is true, I get the form $$\infty^\infty$$ so now I use L.H. but no matter the derivative I get I have no clue how the answer can possibly be $\mathrm{e}$.

Comment: This is the definition of $e$ to some people, so you need to be clear how do you define $e$.

Comment: Does your book offer a definition of $e$? If so please provide it. Otherwise, you may consider defining $e$ as the limit of this (once you show it exists!). You'd just need to show the limit is convergent then. (Hint: either bernoulli's inequality or binomial theorem+monotone convergence test)

Comment: I believe it is e as in 2.718

Comment: @user328129 2.718 is not $e$, as $e$ is irrational and what you wrote is rational

Comment: On wolfram alpha it also displays the answer as e.

Comment: $lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Using L'Hospital rule to $$A_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^ n$$ take logarithms $$\log(A_n)=n\log(1+\frac{1}{n})=\frac{\log(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\frac 1n}$$ Make now $x=\frac 1n$ which makes $$\log(A_n)=\frac{\log(1+x)}x$$ Now, apply the rule $(x\to 0)$

Comment: And yet again a circular application of L'Hopital, used to compute a derivative which one needs to know beforehand to be able to apply L'Hopital... (The invasion of curricula by this so-called *rule* is really a plague, seemingly mortal to any kind of sound thinking...)

Answer (score 1):

In many contexts, this is the very *definition* of $e$.

However if you want:

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(n\ln(1+\frac1n)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \exp\left(\frac{\ln(1+\frac1n)}{n^{-1}}\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+\frac1n)}{n^{-1}} \right)\\
&\stackrel{LR}{=}\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{-n^{-2}}{1+1/n}}{-n^{-2}} \right)\\
&=\exp\left(1\right)\\
&=e
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Isn't it LH, not LR?

Comment: @MXYMXY "LR" is "L'Hopital's Rule"

Comment: How does the "n" from the exponent get in front of "ln" in step 1?

Comment: that's a rule of logarithms

Answer (score 0):

The indeterminate form is actually
$(1+\frac{1}{\infty})^{\infty}
=(\frac{\infty}{\infty})^{\infty}
$.

With regards to
the limit,
there are many proofs here
that show that
$(1+\frac1{n})^n
$ 
is increasing and bounded
and so must have a limit.

Here is one of them:

[Proving : $ \bigl(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\bigr)^{n+1} \gt (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64860/proving-bigl1-frac1n1-bigrn1-gt-1-frac1nn)

Answer (score 0):

If you define $e$ as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1\over k!}={1\over 1}+{1\over 1}+{1\over 2}+{1\over 6}...$ then you have $$(1+\frac1n)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}{1\over n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-k+1)\over k!n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n^k+c_1n^{k-1}+...c_kn^0\over k!n^k}$$

Therefore,$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac1n)^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n^k+c_1n^{k-1}+...c_kn^0\over k!n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{1\over k!}=e$$

Comment: This requires a lot more justification than is given here. In particular, once k is not small compared with n, you might not be able to neglect the terms after $n^k$. At least this has to be proved, not hand-waved away.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\in N$ we have $$1/(n+1)=\int_n^{n+1}1/(n+1)\;dx<\int_n^{n+1}(1/x)\;dx <\int_n^{n+1}1/n\;dx=1/n,$$ $$\text {and }\quad \int_n^{n+1}(1/x)\; dx=\ln (n+1)-\ln n=\ln (1+1/n).$$ $$\text {Therefore }\quad 1/(n+1)<\ln (1+1/n) <1/n$$  $$\text { so }\quad n/(n+1)<\log (1+1/n)^n<1$$ $$\text  {so }\quad e\cdot e^{-1/(n+1)}<(1+1/n)^n<e.$$

Remark: Apply this method to $\ln (1+y/z)=\ln (y+z)-\ln z=\int_z^{y+z}(1/x)\;dx$ for any $y\in R$ and for $\min (1,1-y)<z\in R$ and you obtain $\lim_{z\to \infty}(1+y/z)^z=e^y.$