# A recurrence demonstration

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can someone help me with this:
Demonstrate by recurrence that:
$$ \frac{1}{n!} \leq \left(\frac{e}{n}\right)^n \ \ \ (\forall n>0)$$
Thank you.

Comment: Erm. What have **you** tried already? Clearly, you should at least be able to verify the base case for the induction, and attempt to prove the induction step...

Comment: I recommend refactoring this to $\frac{n^n}{n!} \le e^n$.

Comment: @ClementC. I did verify the case for n=1, after that I multiplied both sides by (1/n+1) so that I get ((1/(n+1)!) But now I'm lost

Comment: @Chris Ooh yeah its way simpler that way when I multiply both sides by n/(n+1) which is clearly smaller than e and I get my results. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1):

Variant not using induction, since $\ln$ is $\nearrow$ on $\mathbb R^+$ then

$\displaystyle \ln(n!)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\ln(k)=\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\ln(k)\ge \int_1^n\ln(t)\mathop{dt}=\bigg[t\ln(t)-t\bigg]_1^n=n\ln(n)-n+1$

Thus $n!\ge n^ne^{-n}e$

---

Proving by recurrence, we need the intermediate result that $\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n\le e$, in fact this sequence is increasing and has limit $e$, this is how we get the inequality.

[I have to show $(1+\frac1n)^n$ is monotonically increasing sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/i-have-to-show-1-frac1nn-is-monotonically-increasing-sequence)

[Proving : $ \bigl(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\bigr)^{n+1} \gt (1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64860/proving-bigl1-frac1n1-bigrn1-gt-1-frac1nn?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Now the induction:

$P(1): \dfrac{1^1}{1!}=1\le e\qquad\checkmark$

$P(n+1): \dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{n!}\le e^n\dfrac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}\le e^n\times (1+\frac 1n)^n\le e^n\times e=e^{n+1}\qquad\checkmark$